# How to open a file stored in a server from aspx page using UNC share path?

Tags: c#, file-io, asp.net-2.0, impersonation

I am listing the files stored in a remote server in the aspx page grid view with the file name linked (href) to the UNC path of the file.
when the user clicks the file name link, it should open the file from the server to allow the user read the file.
I am using impersonation *(Using mirror logon method)* for file upload and delete in the same page which works fine.
When I try to click the link to view the file it throws an error message box saying access denied.
While upoading / deleting file from my application, it uses the impersonated account I specified in web.config.
But it uses default ASP.NET *(SERVER\IUSR_SERVER)* account when trying to access via the link.
I cant give read access to all in my file server share.
**How can I make the application use the impersonated account while trying to access the file for reading through the link I am showing for the files?**

Or please suggest me an better alternative to do the same.

Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you generate the links in the Web page, do not point directly to the UNC, but to a page  of your app, with a parameter to identify the file. In this page, use the same impersonation method to open the file and send its content back to the Web browser.

Comment: Thanks. I used this method and works just fine.
This is how I solved (Might help somebody):

Created a new page (I used a .ashx handler item)

pointed the link to this page with the actual path in query string.

processed the request in the .ashx file. this way it uses the impersonation from my config file.

Comment: ashx is perfect for this. I should have included this in the answer.